# Retrieving object metadata while traversing S3 using Minio client's list_objects method

Tags: python, client, metadata, traversal, minio

I am using the [`list_objects`](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/python/API.html#list_objects) method of the python minio client and trying to retrieve the metadata for each object while traversing folders in S3. I attempted to do this by setting the `include_user_meta` parameter of the method to `True`. However, when I look at the returned objects, the metadata of the returned objects is not included. I checked the S3 API Reference documentation for the [ListObjectsV2 endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) and there is no mention of a `metadata` parameter that could be passed to include the metadata during file traversal.

Is there some other way to retrieve the metadata for each object while traversing a folder in S3 (without firing off one request for each retrieved object), or is this simply not possible and there is a bug in the python minio client?

Comment: I'm using Java client, but got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python API documentation says that *include_user_meta* is "MinIO specific flag to control to include user metadata". Probably other S3 implementations do not support it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).